# Code behaving differently when game is built

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've been dealing with this problem (that started happening for no reason) for the past 3 days, and with deadlines tightening, it's driving me crazy.

So the gist is, the player presses a button, and the camera moves to a location and unlocks the mouse, so the player can click on the interactable (in this case, a diary).

What I've done to try and fix this:

-Created development build, no errors, and nothing in the output.log

-Reimported all the assets

-Started a new project and imported the assets there

-Upgraded from Unity 2018.1 to 2018.3

-Removed the script and attached it again

-Built for different systems

-Restarted Unity and my PC

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DiaryController : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Camera mainCam;
    public float moveSpeed = 10.0f;
    public GameObject cameraObject;
    public GameObject targetObject;
    private bool movingTowardsTarget = false;
    private float lerpSpeed = 0.225f;
    public Transform fromRot;
    public Transform toRot;
    private bool inPosition = false;
    public bool onSwitch = false;

    public bool freezecamera = false;
    public bool freezeplayer = false;

    public WheelchairController Mov;
    public bool EPressed = false;
    public GameObject Crosshair;

    public MouseControl myMouseScript;

    private bool onDiary = false;


    void Start()
    {
        onDiary = false;
        mainCam = Camera.main;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        FreezeCamera();//Checks if the camera has been frozen

        FreezePlayer();//Checks if the player has been frozen


        if (onSwitch && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {

            CheckPlayer();
            EPressed = true;
        }

        if (onSwitch && movingTowardsTarget)
        {
            GoToDiary();
            Crosshair.SetActive(false);
        }
        else if (onSwitch && !movingTowardsTarget && EPressed)
        {
            GoToChair();
            Crosshair.SetActive(true);
        }

    }

    void CheckPlayer()
    {

        if (movingTowardsTarget)
        {
            movingTowardsTarget = false;
            freezecamera = false;
        }

        else
        {
            fromRot = fromRot.transform;
            toRot = toRot.transform;
            // freezecamera = true;
            freezeplayer = true;
            movingTowardsTarget = true;


        }

    }

    void GoToDiary()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DelayFreeze());
        MoveTowardsTarget(targetObject);
        Cursor.visible = true;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;

        Crosshair.SetActive(false);
         freezecamera = true;
        freezeplayer = true;
        onDiary = true;
    }

    void GoToChair()
    {

        StartCoroutine(DelayMov());


        MoveTowardsTarget(cameraObject);
        freezecamera = false;

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Crosshair.SetActive(true);
        onDiary = false;
    }

    IEnumerator DelayMov()
    {
        Debug.Log("DelayActivated");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        freezeplayer = false;

    }

    IEnumerator DelayFreeze()
    {
        if (!freezeplayer)
        {
            Debug.Log("DelayActivated");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            freezeplayer = true;
        }
    }



    void MoveTowardsTarget(GameObject target)
    {

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.rotation = target.transform.rotation;

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) < 0.1)
        {
            inPosition = true;
            Debug.Log("InPosition");

            if (inPosition)
            {
                transform.rotation = target.transform.rotation;

                if (Mathf.Abs(fromRot.localEulerAngles.y - toRot.localEulerAngles.y) < 3)
                {
                    transform.rotation = target.transform.rotation;
                    //movingTowardsTarget = false;
                    inPosition = false;
                    Debug.Log("RotatingCamera");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(fromRot.rotation, toRot.rotation, Time.time * lerpSpeed);
                Debug.Log("RotatingCamera2");
            }
        }
    }

    void FreezeCamera()
    {
        if (freezecamera)
        {
            Debug.Log("CameraFrozen");
            myMouseScript.rotationSpeed = 0.0f;
            // MouseControl.mouseLookEnabled = false;
            ZoomIn.zoomEnable = false;
            Crosshair.SetActive(false);

        }
        else if (!freezecamera)
        {

            myMouseScript.rotationSpeed = 0.5f;
            //MouseControl.mouseLookEnabled = true;
            //ZoomIn.zoomEnable = true;
            //Crosshair.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    void FreezePlayer()
    {
        if (freezeplayer)
        {
            Debug.Log("PlayerFrozen");
            Mov.moveSpeed = 0.0f;
            Mov.turnSpeed = 0.0f;
            Mov.freeze = true;

        }
        else if (!freezeplayer)
        {
            Mov.moveSpeed = 0.4f;
            Mov.turnSpeed = 2.5f;
            Mov.freeze = false;
        }

    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (onSwitch)
        {
            if (!freezeplayer)
            {
                GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 20), "Press E to open diary");

            }
            else
            {
                GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 20), "Press E to close diary");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how it behaves in the editor:
https://i.gyazo.com/4570740f027b736789ed1ab13488bf44.gif

Here's how it behaves in the build:
https://i.gyazo.com/6f1b0485855c24c81abb2278f4361a36.gif

Comment: feels like it's going to a state it should only go after you get to the diary? (book is opened before you got there, etc....). Aren't you setting onSwitch or other boolean differently in editor vs build? I suggest you take a look at the State pattern instead of having multiple booleans to control the flow of your game.

Comment: I guess you have done it but, check you have the same resolution in both debug and build versions. Sometimes some piece of code can use variables that depend on resolution or aspect ratio, it is a noob mistake but it can happen, and the result is what it happened to you. As I can see, some elements of the UI vary size between versions.

Comment: what is the purpose of `DelayedFreeze` if anyway in both occasions you directly set `freezeplayer = true;` immediately?